# How to use fork with signals?

Tags: c, signals, fork

I am unsure of more complicated signals and fork questions. Is there a difference between a signal call from a child or a parent?

When a child is forked, is it now a parent but a child only to the previous parent?

Since a handler is included, is the default handler invalid. So could you change a `SIGINT` to not terminate a process?

```
int count = 0;

void killhandler(int sig){
    printf("SIGKILL received\n");
    return;
}

void childhandler(int sig){
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    count += WEXITSTATUS(status);
    return;
}

main(){
    int i; // for loop iterator
    pid_t pid[3]; // pids of child processes
    Signal(SIGKILL, killhandler);
    Signal(SIGCHLD, childhandler);
    // Fork 3 child processes
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        pid[i] = fork();
        if(!pid[i]){ // If child process
            Signal(SIGKILL, SIG_DFL);
            exit(5);
        }
    }

    // Parent process only
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        kill(pid[i], SIGKILL);
    }
    sleep(5);
    printf("count = %d\n", count);

    exit(0);
}
```

Why is `"SIGKILL received"` never printed?

Why could count only be: 0, 5, 10, 15

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a difference between a signal call from a child or a parent?

In terms of how it impacts the process receiving the signal, no.

> When a child is forked, is it now a parent but a child only to the previous parent?

It is definitely a child of its parent.  Whether it becomes a parent itself depends on whether it forks its own children.

> Since a handler is included, is the default handler invalid. So could you change a SIGINT to not terminate a process?

The default disposition of SIGINT is to terminate the process but you can catch and handle SIGINT or you can block or ignore it. The default disposition isn't so much invalid as overridden until (and if) you change it again.

> Why is "SIGKILL received" never printed?

You can't block, ignore, or catch SIGKILL.  You won't see your handler print anything because it will never be called for SIGKILL.  SIGSTOP, likewise cannot be ignored, blocked or handled.  These are two special signals in that regard.

In your program you are trying to set SIGKILL to its default, in fact its *only*, disposition in the children.  Since your children exit immediately the signal from the parent might never be delivered because the children are dead already and the `kill` in the parent might be failing with ESRCH e.g. no child with that pid exists any longer.  A `sleep` would be helpful there so they can live long enough to be killed.  (Gotta love this terminology.)

Your use of `WEXITSTATUS` is wrong.  If your intent is to count the number of children that exited on their own volition rather than being killed you probably just want a simple counter using WIFEXITED or WIFSIGNALED.  WEXITSTATUS returns the status code of a child that exited on its own.  It could be 0 or 1 or 50 or 75.  Adding it to a variable probably isn't what you want.

Signals are a confusing topic because there are several layers to the onion and there are enough exceptions to the rules and platform specific semantics to make them frustrating.  I have never found a single source that covers them exhaustively.  That said, signal dispositions  and handlers are the outer layer of the onions and there are many sources available on the web that cover these pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

When a child process is forked, it is very close to an exact copy of the parent process. With single-threaded processes, there are three key differences:

1. The parent process ID is different
2. The process ID is different.
3. The return value from `fork()` is different

(For other differences, see the POSIX man page for [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html).) The signal handlers in the child are the same as in the parent.  However, the child can certainly and independently change any of its signal handlers.

You cannot set a signal handler to catch SIGKILL. That signal can never be caught.